# jQuery function working with more data

Tags: jquery, wordpress, function

Can this function work with more ID's to switch for every value checkbox returns? New to jquery, I am not quite sure, I understand this line `var id = $(this).attr('id').match(/-([0-9]*)$/i);`
This function works on my wordpress installation.
[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/avatar876575/zjz44wdd/) does not. Where I get wrong? I expect `div#eg_my_meta_box_Id` to be displayed, only when value is 7 or 8. Any help here?

```
       jQuery(function($)
            {
                function my_check_categories()
                {
                    $('#eg_my_meta_box_id').hide();

                    $('#typeschecklist input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i,e)
                    {
                        var id = $(this).attr('id').match(/-([0-9]*)$/i);

                        id = (id && id[1]) ? parseInt(id[1]) : null ;

                        if ($.inArray(id, [7,8]) > -1 && $(this).is(':checked'))
                        {
                            $('#eg_my_meta_box_id').show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                $('#typeschecklist input[type="checkbox"]').live('click', my_check_categories);

                my_check_categories();
            });
```

Comment: hm. if you want to use this on multiple elements you should use class instead id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function()
                {
                    function my_check_categories()
                    {
                        $('#eg_my_meta_box_id').hide();

                        $('#typeschecklist input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(i,e)
                        {
                            var id = $(this).attr('id').match(/-([0-9]*)$/i);

                            id = (id && id[1]) ? parseInt(id[1]) : null ;

                            if ($.inArray(id, [7,8]) > -1 && $(this).is(':checked'))
                            {
                                $('#eg_my_meta_box_id').show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    $('#typeschecklist input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', my_check_categories);

                    my_check_categories();
                });
```

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zjz44wdd/1/)

Comment: Everything is okey, except the given class. Wordpress `add_meta_box()` function don't accept a class name as a parameter. The only way to sort them is with ID, I guess? What's the deal with IDs unique and class selectors?

Comment: Does the example works? I didnt change anything except begin of the code and the event listener.

Comment: Yes it does. But the problem is, I have about 10 meta boxes per type/category selected and can't give them class and I guess can't give them a same ID too.

Comment: You can't use ID multiple times. That's the big difference between ID and class in css

Comment: So the wordpress function `add_post_meta` accepts only ID as a parameter. If any ideas how I can sort more boxes for that category/type would do a great job! I just have not a clue. Anyway thank you very much for your help, @bksi!